# Can one "smooth over" k-wise independence to get actual independence?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, random-matrices, random-permutations

I came across the following toy problem and was curious if there was a simple solution or counterexample.  Suppose you have a distribution $p$ on $m$ random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_m$, each with finite alphabet of size $a$, satisfying

(i) for some $n<m$, $X_{n+1}, \ldots, X_m$ are i.i.d. with the uniform distribution (as well as independent from $X_1,\ldots, X_n$), and

(ii) $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are $k$-wise independent, and again each marginal is distributed uniformly.

Consider the distribution formed by first choosing $(X_1,\ldots,X_m) \sim p$ and then randomly permuting the coordinates. Is the resulting distribution close (in total variation) to the uniform distribution for some choice of parameters $m,n,k,a$?

I've convinced myself that in the best case: for $k=n-1$ and $m =\operatorname{poly}(n)$, one can expect that the statistical distance between the resulting distribution and the uniform distribution is negligible in $n$, even with the alphabet size exponential in $n$.  To see this, consider the case where the $X_i$ is drawn from $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ and $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i$.

Comment: Do you also mean to assume that $X_{n+1},\dots,X_m$ are independent of $X_1,\dots, X_n$?

Comment: Yes! I'll edit that now, thank you.

Comment: Sorry but what is $\mathbb{F}_2^n$? And how is this different from hierarchical exchangeable case?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ usually denotes the vector space of dimension $n$ over the field of size 2, with elements $0,1$ and arithmetic mod 2.